# Tag-to-tag conversions in Puddletag

Tags: music, id3

Using Puddletag's tag panel, I can create an Album name in the following format:

`George Orwell - Animal Farm`

I'd then like to create Title names using this format:

```
George Orwell - Animal Farm 01 
George Orwell - Animal Farm 02 
George Orwell - Animal Farm 03 
etc.
etc.
```

In tag code, that would translate into:

`%album% %track%`

I don't see the option to do this, i.e., to append a track code to an album code.  I see tag-to-file conversions and file-to-tag conversions, but I don't see tag-to-tag conversions.  Am I overlooking something?

If Puddletag can't do this, are there other tag editors with a simlar spreadsheet-type layout that would allow tag-to-tag conversions?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

This can actually be done using the `Format value` function. (Textual `Functions` button in the top toolbar, then ~sixth entry in the drop down menu.)

In the first text text input, specify which field you want to replace. In your example, `title`. In the second text input, specify the value you want to give it. In your example, `%album% %track%`. The `%{fieldName}%` patterns will be interpolated.